# How do I remove the padding around the icons on my desktop so that they look normal?

Tags: desktop, windows-11, desktop-icons

Ever since upgrading to Windows 11, my desktop icons have an insane amount of spacing around them. It looks like my computer is somehow in some sort of tablet mode, but I can't find any setting to turn this off. Is there a setting somewhere that would fix this problem? I have been on other Windows 11 PC's that don't have this issue, so I know it must be possible somehow.

[image: Desktop Icons]

Thanks!

Comment: [Desktop Icons Spacing is Messed Up in Windows](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/desktop-icons-spacing-messed-up-fix/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open the Registry Editor and go to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics`

For horizontal spacing, double-click `IconSpacing`

For vertical spacing, double-click `IconVerticalSpacing`

The number to modify can be found in the Value data field.

The default starting number should be about -1125. You can change that number from -480 (closest) to -2730 (farthest).

Comment: In addition to the answer posted, you can also hold down the Ctrl Key and roll the mouse button to make icons bigger and smaller. That reduces spacing if smaller.

Comment: Thanks! No clue why a fresh windows 11 install would have these values set so weird...

Answer (score 0):

Right click on Desktop and choose any option that suits you from the view menu that is on top of the Desktop context menu. This happened when I just updated to Windows 11 and this trick worked for me.

[image: Desktop context menu with View submenu opened. Three options are marked: Large icons, Medium icons, Small icons.]

Comment: That doesn't change the horizontal spacing.

Comment: If you look at my screenshot you can see that I am not using large icons. The spacing was messed up and the only fix was to manually edit the registry per @Gantendo's answer